# Azure B2C - Can the Microsoft Graph BETA API be used to create B2C Applications?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

Attempting to use the following Microsoft Graph API call:

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/

To create a new Azure AD B2C Application.  **Is this supported?**

Apps created using https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/ endpoint are listed on Azure Portal -> Azure AD B2C -> Applications but portal is not able to load B2C app details when we click on the app. There appears to be some difference between how app is created from Azure Portal UI and Graph API.

Comment: Seems to be in private preview at the moment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/19975480-programmatically-register-b2c-applications

Answer (score 0):

Calling that endpoint will not work. The applications created within the B2C blade are different to the ones created within the AD Blade (Which is what that beta endpoint uses).

From my understanding, Applications created within the B2C Blade are created as part of the trust framework not part of your AD Tenant.

Comment: can you take a look at my related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775883/where-can-i-view-azure-ad-apps-created-through-microsoft-graph-beta-api